# Taxi Cab Geometry: Correct way to describe the discrepancy between "stair step" & diagonal lines?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

The taxi-cab geometry problem is described here: https://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/taxicab-geometry-4941

In what way is a diagonal line different than a zig-zag line following its path as described in taxi-cab-geometry? Is a diagonal line considered to be "off grid", in another dimension? What is an accurate way to describe the difference/relationship?

[image]

In the above image all the total length of the zig-zag line is equal to $CA+AB$

The diagonal is equal to $\sqrt{CA^2 + AB^2}$

You can approximate the irrational number $pi$ like so:

[image]

But the same does the apply the first example.  In what way are these two examples different? Both start off with apparent low-resolution approximations, but one does approximate an irrational number while the other does not?

Comment: The difference is that the *slopes* of the line segments are converging in the second example, but not in the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that any method you use to try to formalize the idea of how curves can vary and relate to one another will satisfy one (or both!) of the following two properties:

- Stairsteps do not converge to the diagonal
- Length is not a continuous function on curves

For example, one of the things we might want to insist on for convergence is for both points and slopes to converge, rather than just points. Clearly, the slope of the stairsteps does not converge to the slope of the diagonal, since the former are always (when defined) in the set $\{ 0, \infty \}$, but the slopes of the latter are always $1$.

Comment: So would it be accurate to say that diagonals are related to exponential growth and the stairsteps linear growth?

Comment: @Cggart: I fail to see any such relationship.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw the diagonal line $\ell$ or your staircase lines $\sigma_N$ with a thick felt pen then for sufficiently large $N$ the staircases will be in the black area of $\ell$, and $\ell$ will be in the black area of the $\sigma_N$. This means that the Hausdorff distance between $\sigma_N$ and $\ell$ converges to zero, or that $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sigma_N=\ell\tag{1}$$ in the space of nonempty compact sets according to the Hausdorff metric.

But this (very intuitive) metric cannot handle lengths properly: As others have remarked we may have $(1)$ for a sequence of curves, but the lengths of the approximating curves do not converge to the length of the limit curve.